# Import data from a csv to Mysql table using a stored procedure

Tags: mysql, csv, stored-procedures

The following query does the Job:
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:/x/y.csv' 
INTO TABLE test 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 ROWS;

But i want to achieve the same by using a Stored procedure. Have come across various discussions where it is mentioned that "Load Data" cannot be used in a Stored procedure, but i couldn't find an alternate option to do this.

Can some one please provide other alternatives which can be used to load data from CSV to Mysql table using a stored procedure. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a external script that does the LOAD DATA, then in the stored procedure use sys_exec to execute that command.

Comment: Without context I cannot tell, maybe you can try CONCAT to compose a SQL statement and execute it.